# Javascript / Jquery - Get number from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

the string looks like this

```
"blabla blabla-5 amount-10 blabla direction-left"
```

How can I get the number just after `"amount-"`, and the text just after `"direction-"` ?

Comment: Following what rule? Extract all numbers? What is the desired outcome, an array?

Comment: no, just the number/string after those parameters. output should be a string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and the [exec method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var s = "blabla blabla-5 amount-10 blabla direction-left";
var amount = parseInt(/amount-(\d+)/.exec(s)[1], 10);
var direction = /direction-([^\s]+)/.exec(s)[1];
```

The code will cause an error if the amount or direction is missing; if this is possible, check if the result of exec is non-null before indexing into the array that should be returned.

Answer (score 38):

This will get all the numbers separated by coma:

```
var str = "10 is smaller than 11 but greater then 9";
var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
var matches = str.match(pattern);
```

After execution, the string `matches` will have values `"10,11,9"`

If You are just looking for thew first occurrence, the pattern will be `/[0-9]+/` - which will return `10`

(There is no need for JQuery)

Answer (score 6):

You can use regexp as explained [by w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp). Hint:

```
str = "blabla blabla-5 amount-10 blabla direction-left"
alert(str.match(/amount-([0-9]+)/));
```

Otherwize you can simply want all numbers so use the pattern [0-9]+ only.
str.match would return an array.