# jQuery - "argument parser" for classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm trying to configure jQuery plugins trough classes applied to elements to which these plugins are attached.

for example:

```
<div class="move amt-10 dir-left">
...
</div>
```

and the js:

```
$('.move').each(function(){
  var classes = $(this).attr('class');

  // this is from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955345/javascript-jquery-get-number-from-string
  var amount = parseInt(/amt-(\d+)/.exec(classes)[1], 10);
  var direction = /dir-([^\s]+)/.exec(classes)[1];
  // do stuff here based on amount/direction variables
});
```

it works for this particular case, but since I'm doing this for other plugins too, I was wondering how could create some kind of "parser" for this kind of options passed trough classes, so I can write less code :)

Comment: Does this have to work with existing third-party code so you're forced to use class attribute? Because it looks like you are abusing classes to implement `data`: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: no, I just like the fact that you can control a plugin from the html. is this a bad idea?

Comment: Using `jQuery.data` you have access to HTML5 `data-` attributes, look at the examples provided in docs linked above. In your use case it could be `<div class="move" data-amt="10">`//posted as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example refactored using [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and HTML5 data-* attributes

```
<div class="move" data-amt="10" data-dir="left"></div>

$('.move').each(function(){
  var amount = $(this).data('amt');
  var direction = $(this).data('dir');
  // do stuff here based on amount/direction variables
});
```

Comment: yeah, that's the point of using jQuery :) you should test it yourself, but I see no reason why a cross-browser framework feature  wouldn't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Another good option for this sort of thing is the jquery metadata plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata