# jQuery - check whether string contains numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check whether a string contains any numeric value by jquery?

I search through many examples but I only get the way to check for a number, NOT number in a STRING. I am trying to find something like `$(this).attr('id').contains("number");`

(p/s: my DOM id will be something like `Large_a` (without numeric value) , `Large_a_1` (with numeric value), `Large_a_2`, etc.)

What method should I use?

Comment: One of the first google search results:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955345/javascript-jquery-get-number-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code detects trailing digits preceded by the *underscore* symbol (**azerty1_2** would match "2", but **azerty1** would not match):

```
if (matches = this.id.match(/_(\d)+$/))
{
    alert(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: There's no need for grouping, *test* is likely more appropriate (*match* returns an array of matches, *test* just tests). So `if (/_\d+$/.test(this.id)) {...}`. Nice catch that the OP may only want trailing numbers. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I just love short code... and we never know whether the number's value will be needed or not  :-)

Comment: Get it done by: if (ui.draggable.children().attr('id').match(/_(\d+)$/) != null)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var matches = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches != null) {
    // the id attribute contains a digit
    var number = matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple version:

```
function hasNumber(s) {
  return /\d/.test(s);
}
```

More efficient version (keep regular expression in a closure):

```
var hasNumber = (function() {
    var re = /\d/;
    return function(s) {
      return re.test(s);
    }
}());
```

Comment: I'm curious how much more efficient your closurised version is? I gather that the overhead of the closure is worth it to avoid recreating the regular expression every time?