# Remove entire word from string if it contains numeric value

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What I'm trying to accomplish is to auto-generate tags/keywords for a file upload, basing these keywords from the filename.

I have accomplished auto-generating **titles** for each upload, as shown here:
[image]

But I have now moved on to trying to auto-generate **keywords**. Similar to titles, but with more formatting. First, I run the string through **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686839)** to remove commonly used words from the filename (such as `this,that,there`... etc)

I am happy with it, but I need to **not include words that have numbers in it**. I have not found a solution on how to remove a word entirely if it contains a number. The solutions I have found like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660107/jquery-check-whether-string-contains-numeric-value) only works for a certain match, while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2878362/1399030) removes numbers alone. **I would like to remove the entire word if it contains ANY numeric digit.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all words which contain a number, use:

```
string = string.replace(/[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*/gi, '');
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, this was a very good answer. It does exactly the job I needed done however when a word containing a number starts in capital case (ex. `Amazon1`) it leaves the capital letter there (returning `A`). However, I *strtolowered* the string before running it with this and now it's perfect! :) bravo ... **Edit** I see you fixed the issue with the caps, so now it's absolutely perfect without my help, thanks so much! Just what I needed

Comment: @Love The `i` flag makes the regular expression case-insensitive. See my original answer for an explanation on the regular expression pattern. Here's MDN's guide for Regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Engineer Thanks for your time, I was trying out the first solutions provided and 1 worked before I got to your answer. :)

Comment: @RobW I believe, that the OP splits the string by '`-_`', only then applies replacement. See the samples in question's pic.

Comment: No, there is no pattern used in my filenames, they are images submitted by users. Those are just plain filenames :) nothing done to filenames that should help affect anything

Comment: @Love Engineer means that the hyphens are replaced with spaces. Your file name can be turned in tags by using `string.split(/[^a-b]/i)`.

Comment: @Love Probably you need to define, what do you mean by '`word`' noun. What are words?  Is '`word1-word2`' represents 2 words, or 1 word? Similar situation with '`word1_word2`'

Comment: My `words` come from the string in the title field. When I say string, it's those titles. I base the word tags from the title.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a simple regular expression to you current filename strings, replacing all occurrences with the empty string. The regular expression matches "words" containing any digits.

Javascript example:

```
'asdf 8bit jawesome234 mayhem 234'.replace(/\s*\b\w*\d\w*\b/g, '')
```

Evaluates to:

```
"asdf mayhem"
```

Here the regular expression is `/\s*\b\w*\d\w*\b/g`, which matches maximal sequences consisting of zero or more whitespace characters (`\s*`) followed by a word-boundary transition (`\b`), followed by zero or more alphanum characters (`\w*`), followed by a digit (`\d`), followed by zero or more alphanum characters, followed by a word-boundary transition (`\b`). `\b` matches the empty string at the transition to an alphanumeric character from either the beginning or end of the word or a non-alphanumeric character. The `g` after the final `/` of the regular expression means replace all occurrences, not just the first.

Once the digit-words are removed, you can split the string into keywords however you want (by whitespace, for example).

```
"asdf mayhem".split(/\s+/);
```

Evaluates to:

```
["asdf", "mayhem"]
```

Comment: Hello @Maxy-B, but it is unable to remove the entire word, this only removes the number and I was hoping to remove entire words. (not just the number) Example: `2morrow tomorrow`, then I would just wish to return `tomorrow` and remove `2morrow` entirely from the string because it contains a number (so the keywords won't look broken, otherwise I would have a `morrow` keyword.) :)

Comment: Edited to remove a word if it contains one or more digits (whether the whole word is digits or not).

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
 var regex = /\b[^\s]*\d[^\s]*\b/g;
```

Example:

```
 var str = "normal 5digit dig555it digit5 555";
 console.log( str.replace(regex,'') );​   //Result->  normal
```

Comment: 1. The word boundaries are unnecessary. 2. In the screenshot (see question), the words seems to be delimited by hyphens. The result for `"normal-5"' is `""`, using your code.

Comment: @RobW Probably they are unnecessary, but I have written regexp for general case.

Comment: @RobW and just to point it out, the OP is already spliting the string to make the title.... could just run this regex against the title after the split;)

Answer (score 1):

```
('Apple Cover Photo 23s423 of your 543634 moms').match(/\b([^\d]+)\b/g, '')
```

returns

Apple Cover Photo , of your , moms

http://jsfiddle.net/awBPX/2/

Answer (score 0):

use this to Remove words containing numeric :

```
string.replace("[0-9]","");
```

hope this helps.

**Edited :**

check this :

```
var str = 'one 2two three3 fo4ur 5 six';
var result = str.match(/(^[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+\s|\s[\D]+$|^[\D]+$)+/g).join('');
```

Comment: No this will replace all occurrences of any digit, regardless of whether they constitute an entire word. For example, "8bit mayhem" would become "bit mayhem".

Comment: oops! i got you. any word start with numeric and end with numeric. is this what you mean?

Comment: "one 2two three3 fo4ur 5 six" should become "one six"

Comment: i am thinking i found it.check my post.