# What's a jQuery script for selecting any number mentioned within a divs class and then adding a class to that number?

Tags: jquery, css

If a div has a class of 'motto' and within that div it says, "Celebrating 24 years in the business!" I'd like a script that finds any number mentioned in that div (because it could change next year to 25 for example, and so forth, hence I'm not wanting to get the number specifically), I'd like it to add a span with a class to it. Possible?

The reason is that it pulls this text from the WordPress 'description' in settings, so I can't directly put the number in a span. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a span around the number you need to target? or do you not have control over the content of the div?

Comment: Right, I can't add a span because it's pulled form the WordPress 'description' in settings.

Comment: well I am sure you can exract the number with regex but I am terrible at regex. Or if the text is the same words, you can exact it using substrings as well. Perhaps tis can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955345/javascript-jquery-get-number-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it messily with some string manipulation:

```
var motto = $('.motto'),
    num = motto.text().match(/\d+/), // regex matching digits
    text = motto.text().replace(num, '<span class="num">'+num+'</span>');

motto.html(text);
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/uxuhuv/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works great. It's in use here: http://tomalakgranite.com/ if anyone's interested to see.