# jquery: extract value from $(this)

Tags: jquery, extract, numeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript / Jquery - Get number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955345/javascript-jquery-get-number-from-string)

Using

```
var id = $(this).attr("class");
```

I get all the classes of the clicked link, var id returns 4 classes:

```
button_red 501 ajax-call class2
```

How do I extract the class '501' and put it in an var like `var id_numeric = 501` ?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Can't help wondering why do you need to use classes to store what looks like semantic data.

Comment: usually I would store it in the ID, in this case the ID is already taken by something else (drupal ajax link). I understand you're wondering ;)

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var numericClassIdMatches = $(this).attr('class').match(/\b\d+\b/);
```

In the above case, `501` would be `numericClassIdMatches[0]`

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked! will accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: btw, if you want, can you exlain the (/\b\d+\b/) part? I don't see any logic in it

Comment: @MaartenHartman http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: I am downvoting this not because it doesn't work, but because it's perpetuating a poor design decision, which is to put semantic data in a `class` attribute, rather than storing it in a more accessible format, such as [`[data-*]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attributes.

Comment: @zzzzBov thank you for at least explaining

Comment: It should also be noted that classes cannot start with numbers.  `501` would not be considered a valid class name.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number

Comment: @zzzzBov I appreciate your comment. I'm not sure I can do what you suggest with drupal ajax links..

Comment: As @zzzzBov mentioned, you should not be using classes to store data values.

Comment: @Axel the class name restriction you are referencing does not exist in the current HTML spec

Comment: just for extra knowledge: what is the real argument to not put data in classes?

Comment: @MaartenHartman because look at how relatively complex it was to get the ID data you were looking for! `$(this).attr('class').match(/\b\d+\b/)[0];` vs. `$(this).data('id')`.  Also, classes may be manipulated by other means (`$(this).removeClass()` will remove the ID class as well as the styling classes)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using an HTML5 doctype, you could probably use a `data-` attribute rather than a CSS class. For example:

```
data-id="501"
```

Then either

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

or

```
var id = $(this).data("id"); //[1]
```

would work.

Reference:

[1] http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method/

Comment: This is the right tool for the job.

Comment: data attributes have been around for awhile actually http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: @wirey, data attributes have been *supported* for a while, but they weren't standardized until the HTML5 spec, which would require the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Thanks to you too Tieson, I will remember this for the future. I'm using drupal 7 ajax links, therefore I can't use it yet (done some googling)